# Nextion with Arduino change text

Tags: arduino, serial-port, nextion

I'm working with a display nextion NX8048T070, i'm trying to change a text with a serials instructions
In the Nextion debug the code works and text change, but in my display didn't change, I used software serial and nextion library (all it)

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("t0.txt=");     // This is sent to the nextion display to set what object name (before the dot) and what atribute (after the dot) are you going to change.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.print("De entrada");  // This is the text you want to send to that object and atribute mentioned before.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.write(0xff);          // We always have to send this three lines after each command sent to the nextion display.
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);

  delay(1000);
  
  Serial.print("t0.txt=");     // This is sent to the nextion display to set what object name (before the dot) and what atribute (after the dot) are you going to change.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.print("Apoco si");  // This is the text you want to send to that object and atribute mentioned before.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.write(0xff);          // We always have to send this three lines after each command sent to the nextion display.
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: "I used software serial and nextion library (all it)". Don't know what exactly you are trying to do with this code, but did you try the examples (15 of them) that come with the library? or read the [documentation](https://nextion.tech/editor_guide/)?

Comment: I just want a Nextion screen text box to change with the arduino